# How to loop over JSON response with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops

I'm using the following ajax:

```
       $.ajax({ 
                 type: 'POST', 
                 url: '/search/search.php', 
                 crossDomain: true,
                 data:  {data: data},
                 dataType: 'json', 
                 async: false,

                 success: function (response){ 
                    if (response.success) 
                        {
                           $('#search-results').show();

                           for(field in response.data){

                           error = response.field_errors[field];           

                               var name = field.name;
                               var barcode = field.barcode;
                               var serial = field.serial;

                               $("#searchname").html(name);
                               $("#searchbarcode").html(barcode);
                               $("#searchserial").html(serial);


                           }
                        } 
                    else {
                        console.log("fail");
                    }
                 },

               });
```

I'm trying to loop through the rows returned from the php, and put each row as a row in the table of my html.. I get the correct response from the php, but my loop doesn't show anything in the html.

HTML Table

```
        <table class="table" id="search-results" style="display:none;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Serial</th>
              <th>Barcode</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td id="searchname"></td>
              <td id="searchbarcode"></td>
              <td id="searchserial"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

PHP

```
    $json = array();
    if($num > 0)
    {

        $json['success'] = TRUE;
        $i = 0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
    $json[$i]['data']['name'] = $row['name'];
    $json[$i]['data']['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
    $json[$i]['data']['serial'] = $row['serial'];

    $i++;
}
    }
    else
    {
        $json['success'] = FALSE;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: What is wrong ? What do you expect it to do ? What does it do instead ? Please ask a real question.

Comment: I'm trying to add a row to my html table for each row in the php response. It currently doesn't show anything on the html but gives me the correct json response from the php

Comment: Why are you using a loop? As ID's are unique, you will only overwrite your values with each row. And what does `console.log(field);` give you in the loop?

Comment: I don't want to overwrite my values, I've updated my question with the code of my table. is there a way to generate html for each row?

Comment: Sure, just generate a html string or jQuery objects in the loop (adding to the previous result instead of overwriting) and append it to your table after the loop.

Comment: Also `var name = field.name;` in `for..in` doesn't make sense. You probably need `var name = response.data[field].name;`. And the same for `barcode` and `serial`.

Comment: could you show me an example? I'm not used to working with javascript so I'm not familiar with the syntax

Comment: I get the correct response from the php, the javascript doesn't show any data on the html page, only makes the table visible

Comment: @user1738017 I have updated my answer, it should now work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery .each(). to itterate the array, and jquerys .append() to add the table rows:

If the data is an array of objects:

```
$.each(response.data, function( index, item ) {
    $('#search-results').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.barcode + '</td><td>' + item.serial + '</td><td></tr>');
});
```

If its an array of arrays:

```
$.each(response.data, function( index, item ) {
    $('#search-results').append('<tr><td>' + item['name'] + '</td><td>' + item['barcode'] + '</td><td>' + item['serial'] + '</td><td></tr>');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

EDIT you php creates odd json, hence your problems. Fix it up:

```
$json = array();
if($num > 0)
{

    $json['success'] = TRUE;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
          $json['data'][]=array('name'=>$row['name'], 'barcode'=>$row['barcode'], 'serial'=>$row['serial']);
    }
}
else
{
    $json['success'] = FALSE;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: object is undefined length = object.length`

Comment: @user1738017 please edit your question to show me the contents of response.data, eg with console.log(response.data); or just show the php code that creates it in the 1st place.

Comment: the full response is `{"success":true,"0":{"data":{"name":"carla","barcode":null,"serial":"test"}},"1":{"data":{"name":"test","barcode":null,"serial":"test"}}}`

Comment: @user1738017 your json is messed up. I have edited my answer to fix it for you.

Comment: I've changed it but now I see this error ` <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant serial - assumed 'serial' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search/search.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant serial - assumed 'serial' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search/search.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
{"success":true,"data":[{"name":"carla","barcode":null,"serial":"test"},{"name":"test","barcode":null,"serial":"test"}]}`

Comment: @user1738017 missed some quotes, fixed now. Glad you got it working